# how to pass value to crystal report parameter filed from the code

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am creating crystal report like this:

```
Dim whereClass As String = ""

            sql = "SELECT * from v_LPO where PO_NUM = '" & txt_Po_No.Text & "'"
            ' where invoice_num='PI/2014/00001'"

            ds = New DataSet
            ds.Clear()
            ds.Tables.Clear()

            ds = Fn_Return_Dataset(sql)
            Dim slFilter As New SortedList
            slFilter.Clear()
            Dim objrpt As New frmrptengine(AppPath & "\reports\rptPurchaseOrder.rpt", ds)

            objrpt.machineName = machineName

            objrpt.Show()
```

in my rptPurchaseOrder.rpt i have a parameter field name `PONAME`. I want to pass manually value to my parameter field from the code? how i can do in this case?

any help is very appreciable..

Comment: What is the return type of `frmrptengine`?

Comment: (http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_parameter_string.htm)[Follow this Link]

Comment: You can use [`ReportDocument` Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa665784%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in your code and access to its parameters by using [`DataDefinition` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645537%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and use property of `ParameterFields` ;).